# Roundcube issues after upgrade

Tags: apache2, mysql, roundcube

Ubuntu Server 22.04.3 LTS with MySQL and Apache 2

I performed the roundcube upgrade to 1.6.3 and now am getting this message in the logs:

```
PHP Warning:  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'roundcube'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /opt/www/roundcubemail-1.3.0/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube.php on line 1503
```

Yes, it says `roundcube 1.3.0`, but that's the directory linked via symlink to the `/opt/www/roundcube` directory.

The password is in the config file, and nothing else changed. The roundcube upgrade script ran successfully.

I feel like I'm missing something simple.  Searching out the error, I see errors with `USING PASSWORD: YES`, but in my case it's apparently not using the password.

Comment: From the error, it sounds like that password is not being passed to the MySQL connection string. Have you confirmed that the configuration file has not changed its structure over the past few versions?

Comment: The config file didn't change, and the password is still in the file.